# access Google Data

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to access the Google data by using Google api ?
I mean is it possible to make my own search engine  for android by using the google ready made api ???

If yes then how ??
Thanks in advance. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use Google Local Search API in your application . It needs JSON parsing

here is the linkhttp://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/jsondevguide.html#basic_query

Comment: Ohh Thanks Budy. ..  Do you have any sample or demo application for it about hoe to use it ??

Comment: I want to make a Books Search for My Application. . .  Is there any Sample for it. . .  If you have can you post it. . .? Thanks in Advance. . .